# WCF Serialization with object inheritance?

Tags: wcf, .net-3.5, serialization

I have two objects, one is in our enterprise level and another in in our service level. The service object is inheriting from the enterprise. Here is a quick example:

```
[DataContract]
public class EnterpriseObject{
     [DataMember]
     int ID{get; set;}

     string InternalUse{get; set;}
}

[DataContract]
public class ServiceObject: EnterpriseBaseObject{
     [DataMember]     
     string Address{get; set;}
}
```

Is it possible to only expose the ServiceObject (with inherited properties from EnterpriseObject) in the serialization? I do not want the client to see the enterprise object listed as an option? As you can see in the example the DataMember attribute is not set for the InternalUser property. Is that the only way to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You handle inheritance by adding a `[KnownType(typeof(ServiceObject))]` to `EnterpriseBaseObject` - however, the `EnterpriseBaseObject` is still part of the contract, and its existance will be public. But only members marked `[DataMember]` will be published.

One option (to remove the inheritance) is to have a separate DTO for serialization purposes, and have a conversion between the DTO version and the actual version - but that makes extra work.

Answer (score 2):

Can you change this from an Is A pattern to a Has A pattern? If ServiceObject has an EnterpriseObject you could then expose just the properties you need.

## Edit

If I understand correctly you want to expose ServiceObject to clients including all its properties (That are marked as a DataMember) including properties inherited from EnterpriseObject. But you don't want the client to know that there is an object called EnterpriseObject.

You can do this by hidding the fact that there is an enterprise object. Instead of using an "Is A" relationship which is an inheritance pattern. You can use a composition or "Has A" pattern.

```
public class ServiceObject
{
   private EnterpriseObject _myEntObject;

   public string MyServiceObjectProperty
   {
      get;
      set;
   }

   public string MyEntObjectProperty
   {
     get { return _myEntObject.MyEntObjectProperty;}
   }
}
```

Now you have isolated your EnterpriseObject from your client. All your communicating is that ServiceObject has some properties you are not exposing to your client that this is implemented on the server by some other object.

This is also simillar to having a DTO, which is an object that's sole purpose is to transmit data. DTO's allow you hide your implementation by giving your clients exactly what they need in the format they need, without exposing your internal objects.

Comment: Not sure what you mean here. Could you explain?

Comment: I see what you are saying. That is an interesting approach! Thanks!