# Is there any way to hide/flatten base types in WCF service data contracts?

Tags: wcf, datacontract, datacontracts

Consider the following simple example:

```
[DataContract("{0}Base")]
public class Base<T> where T : Entity<T>
{
    // Common methods & properties.  No WCF exposed properties
}

[DataContract]
public class Employee : Base<Employee>
{
    // WCF exposed properties
}
```

The base class Base has no properties of interest to the WCF service consumers, but WCF forces me to also annotate the Base class with a [DataContract] attribute.  This essentially shows up on the service client as `Employee : EmployeeBase` with `EmployeeBase` being an empty class with no properties.

I do not want to expose the `Base<T>` class to the service in this way, so what are my options?

1. DTO for the Employee class - I'd rather not add this complexity
2. "Flatten" the DataContract hierarchy so that the data contract for Employee does not expose that it inherits from `Base<T>`.  Is this possible?  How?
3. Other solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each class in hiearchy has to be serializable / DataContract. If you don't want to expose hiearchy you have to use DTO or you can try to implement IDataContractSuroggate for your Employee class.

Comment: Looks like DTO or just accepting that the base object will be exposed. Actually, just stumbled upon this question, which I guess makes mine a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/658361/wcf-serialization-with-object-inheritance