# Suppress DataContract base class in the proxy in WCF

Tags: wcf

I have Base class for all the DataContracts in my WCF services. When the client is consuming 2 WCF services, both the proxies contain the Base class definition and thus client is not compiling. I tried with giving different namespaces for the derived data contracts, services - nothing worked.

I googled and found 'ServiceKnownType' attribute would address this issue - but didn't work.

I understand the service nature that they should be independent and shouldn't share the contract. But am curious to solve this scenario...any pointers please

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any way to hide/flatten base types in WCF service data contracts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499788/is-there-any-way-to-hide-flatten-base-types-in-wcf-service-data-contracts)

Answer (score 1):

You may put your entities in a separate assembly and reference this assembly in both the client and service.
Make sure your service references are configured with the "Use types in referenced assemblies" activated. This can be checked by right-clicking the service reference and selecting "Configure service reference".

Comment: We considered this option; and want to go with Channel factory implementation rather than a Service reference. I have two deliverable - Service and UI. I am looking for a way thru which we can suppress the Base Class into all proxes - using Attributes or some configuration?